# Not being able to install LinkChecker

Tags: installation, pip

I'm having issues installing broken link-checker.
When I do 'sudo pip install LinkChecker' like said in installation, I get following error

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-uBq7xh/LinkChecker/setup.py", line 95, in <module>
        import py2app
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py2app/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
        __version__ = pkg_resources.require('py2app')[0].version
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 968, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 854, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'macholib>=1.4' distribution was not found and is required by py2app

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-uBq7xh/LinkChecker/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get suggests you fail to meet the dependencies needed for the package you're installing.
Try installing macholib and upgrading pip, as suggested by the log

`pip install macholib`

`pip install --upgrade pip`